# Apache virtual host for drupal test site

Tags: apache-2.2, drupal

I am a programmer, trying to launch my first website.. through different helpful posts in sf and others, I setup an account with Linode  and set up a slice (Debian, Apache, ..etc). I have a Drupal site under development, and like to have a test site in the Linode server as well. Now, I like to have a site setup with the following requirement.

1. What is the best way to setup and protect the test site along with the actual (production) site?. Is virtual host is the answer?
2. To protect the test site, is .htaccess authentication sufficient to prevent access from public and robots?

I also modifying the theme, database contents etc, so having two sites under one drupal installation may not be good idea . what do u suggest?

thanks in advance.
bsreekanth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help and is what I used:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Name-based is probably the most common unless you need SSL.

Comment: yes, I used "Running different sites on different ports". thanks

Answer (score 0):

you set you Drupal multiple as follow:

Server configuration

`# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80`
`Listen 80`

`# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses`
`NameVirtualHost *:80`

`<VirtualHost *:80>`
`DocumentRoot /www/example1`
`ServerName www.example1.com`

`# Other directives here`

`</VirtualHost>`

`<VirtualHost *:80>`
`DocumentRoot /www/example2`
`ServerName www.example2.org`

`# Other directives here`

`</VirtualHost>`

[How to Drupal](http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/06/lamp-on-drupal-installation-and.html)